# asp listview datasource appending

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

everytime I refresh the page, the listview, which brings a set of records from the database, is changing, for example if i have 3 records and i add another record (4th one), when I refresh the page, it seems that the 4 records are APPENDED to the listview!

```
protected void listComment_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listViewComment.DataSource = Connect.ExecuteSelect(CommandBuilder.GetAllComments());
        listViewComment.DataBind();
    }
```

Do I need to use some sort of refresh or clear first? I am invoking this method on listview load.

---

ASPX Page, ListView Control:

```
<asp:ListView ID="listViewComment" runat="server" OnLoad="listComment_Load" class="container-commentBox">
                    <LayoutTemplate>
                        <h1>
                            Shout Box
                        </h1>
                        <div id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
                    </LayoutTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div>
                            <%# Eval("username") %>:
                            <br />
                            <%# Eval("comment") %>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemSeparatorTemplate>
                        <hr />
                    </ItemSeparatorTemplate>
```

ExecuteSelect:

```
public static DataSet ExecuteSelect(string query)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.CommandText = query;
            command.Connection = connection;
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;

            using (adapter)
            {
                adapter.Fill(dataSet);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }

        return dataSet;
    }
```

Comment: what do you want exactly? the "append" effect must be invoked automatically after adding the new record or stopping the addition into the listview?

Comment: I want to see what CommandBuilder.GetAllComments() does.

Comment: @EricH it looks like `CommandBuilder.GetAllComments()` does some sort of `select * from comments` or something like that, but I can't understand his actual problem.

Comment: @EricH that method simply calls a query as specified below. My problem is that when a user adds a comment, I would like to display it immediately in the listview, so at first I decided to invoke listView_Load(sender, e). The problem is the first set of records are DUPLICATED and the second set would have the new comment! I am finding this very very strange!

Comment: @test by the way have you set the DataSource in your control (something like `<asp:ListView runat="server" DataSource="someSource">` and then setting a new DataSource in the code behind?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza No i dont have a datasource in my control. but i am starting to think that the new code that i have just inserted in the question, with the 'Eval("username") is the problem. I never used this before.

Comment: the same thing happens if I use a grid view. I don't think the aspx has a problem. Can it be that the dataadapter is filling by appending to the dataset and not starting from the beginning? may be I need to use a NEW Dataset always?

Comment: I found my answer, All i needed to do was to CREATE A NEW DATASET each time the method is called!

so as a first line in ExecuteSelect method we write: DataSet dataSet = new DataSet(); 

if this is not done, records are RE-ADDED, thus resulting in showing records that were already present.

Comment: @test as it looks [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in the "Populating a DataSet from Multiple DataAdapters" section, the dataAdapter.fill(DataSet) just put the new information in the DataSet (doesn't clean it at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer, All i needed to do was to **create** a new `DataSet` each time the method is called!

So as the first line in ExecuteSelect method we write: `DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();`

If we reuse the old dataSet with some records in it, the incoming records are RE-ADDED in the `adapter.fill(dataSet)` call, resulting in showing old and new records mixed in the DataSet.

Comment: Please mark it as an answer: "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green."